# I need help around file access and modification in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, file, audio

I have the folder "segmentation" where i need the use of ".purseg" files(x.purseg,y.purseg,z.purseg). They are kind of text files.
Their form is:

'0.1 4.5 speech_L1'

'4.7 9.2 speech_L2'

etc.

I also have the folder audio where i have the "audio": x.wav,y.wav,z.wav.
Each ".purseg" file matches a ".wav" file,they both have the same name.
For my script i have to get the information from the ".purseg" file and based on it i have to cut from the wav file the part that i need(get the speaker mentioned as speech_L2).I made a script that works if i have both ".purseg" and ".wav" file in the same folder but because i am working with a lot of data i need to fix my script in order to work with folders. Here is the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use File::Copy "cp";
use warnings;


my $directory = '/home/taurete/Desktop/diar_fem_fin/segmentation/';
opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) 
    {
    next unless ($file =~ m/\.purseg$/);    
    $file =~ s{\.[^.]+$}{};     
    push (@list1, $file);   
#   print "$file\n";
    }
my $list=@list1;
#   print "$list";
$i=0;
while ($i<$list)
    {
    my $nume1=$list[$i];
    open my $fh, "$nume1.purseg" or die $!;
    my @file_array;
    while (my $line = <$fh>) 
        {
           chomp $line;
           my @line_array = split(/\s+/, $line);
           push (@file_array, \@line_array);
        }
    my @arr=@file_array;
    $cont1=0;
    my $s1= @arr;
    for (my $i=0;$i < $s1;$i++)
        {
        $directory="$nume1";
        make_path($directory);
        if ("speech_L2" eq "$arr[$i][2]")
            {
            my $directory = '/home/taurete/Desktop/data/audio/';
            opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;
            $interval = $arr[$i][1] - $arr[$i][0];
            $speakername=$nume1._.$cont1;
            `sox $nume1.wav ./$directory/$speakername.wav trim $arr[$i][0] $interval`;
            $cont1++;   
            }   
        }
    $i++;
    }
```

Here is what i get:

> Name "main::list" used only once: possible typo at ./spkfinal.pl line
> 23. Use of uninitialized value $nume1 in concatenation (.) or string at ./spkfinal.pl line 27. No such file or directory at ./spkfinal.pl
> line 27.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about `Name "main::list" used only once: possible typo at ./spkfinal.pl line 23.`, change:

```
my $nume1=$list[$i];
```

to:

```
my $nume1=$list1[$i];
```

You do not have an array `@list`, but you do have an array `@list1`.

I think that will clear up your subsequent warnings, too.